# UITableView becomes slow and unresponsive for no apparent reason

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

It seems that after a little use my app becomes slow and unresponsive on the `UITableViewController`. There are some pretty intensive methods but once these are done there's no reason why they should effect the overall performance of the app.

I've been using instruments to determine what it could be, but it's proving very inconclusive. First off I can't recreate the issue via one method, it just seems to occur from general usage. The main thing using CPU is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` according to thread usage. While I do actually do quite a lot of calculations, it doesn't explain two things. 1) Why this issue develops over time. I can scroll up and down the `TableViewController` several times when I first boot up the app and everything is super smooth. 2) Even when I remove all but 3 or 4 cells the unresponsiveness remains.

Another observation is that a `modal ViewController` has a very smooth animation when the app is first loaded, but ends up having this horrible jagged animation, sometimes only 1 or 2 frames, later on. Again, there are a couple of fairly complex calculations on the dismissal of this Modal (including a managedObjectContext save), and it does close to reveal the `UITableView` beneath (meaning some `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) but there is no way these two things alone can bring the animation to virtually 0 fps. All this has lead me to believe that resources are getting used up and are not returning. Now sadly, I don't know enough about the iOS environment to be sure about the next assumptions, but here goes:

- Memory. Simply put, it can't really be this can it? Even though my app is very memory intensive with lots of images I'm pretty sure iOS removes things from the RAM as it begins to run out. On top of that the diagnostics show that I have had 50MB free when experiencing a huge amount of lag in the app.
- CPU. I thought potentially that something was using up all my CPU like the last time I had performance issues (I had called an infinite loop of a method, whoops) however, the app seems to use CPU only when needed. In other words, it goes back to 0 usage when the app is idle. Just to explain how this is significant; if the CPU, as a resource, was being eaten up by something then it would explain why `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was struggling over time. However, since it's not getting eaten up there's no reason why prolonged usage of the app should cause `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to use too much of the CPU. Therefore I can't see how my issue is caused by the CPU being hogged.

Naturally as those are the only two resources I can think of I am completely and utterly stumped. I have no idea why the app should become slow over time. In effect, I can't see how it can be code as the app works fine when first starting up and I can't see how it can be the resources when there seems to be plenty left.

Since I'm new to Objective-C/iOS development I suspect that there's something I'm missing. If you could help me identify it, I'd really appreciate it.

**UPDATE:** Posting my code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell`:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
myEntityForConfigureCell = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

searchResultForConfigureCell = [searchResults objectForKey:myEntityForConfigureCell.trackId];


// Example of how I fill in cell information. There are far more than shown.
nameLabelForConfigureCell = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
nameLabelForConfigureCell.text = myEntityForConfigureCell.name;

genreLabelForConfigureCell = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1002];
genreLabelForConfigureCell.text = searchResultForConfigureCell.genre;

// Example of how I do the ImageViews using AFNetworking
imageForConfigureCell = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
[imageForConfigureCell setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: searchResultForConfigureCell.artworkURL60]];
imageForConfigureCell.layer.cornerRadius = 9.4;
imageForConfigureCell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

// The RateView for showing a start rating
rateViewForConfigureCell = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(73, 44, 75, 12) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullSmall.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptySmall.png"]];
rateViewForConfigureCell.rate = [searchResultForConfigureCell.rating floatValue];
rateViewForConfigureCell.alignment = RateViewAlignmentLeft;
[cell.contentView addSubview:rateViewForConfigureCell];

// Setting Sections for all Core Data entries only if BOOL isLoading is YES, but **has** finished downloading informaton, i.e. just before completion.

if ([searchResults count] == [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]) {

    if (isLoading) {
        NSLog(@"Is loading so Setting Sections");
        isLoading = NO;
        [self cycleThroughEntriesAndSetSection];
    }
    else if (!isLoading){
        [loadingHudView removeFromSuperview];
    }

}

}
```

And now for `willDisplayCell`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
myEntityForDisplayCell = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
searchResultForDisplayCell = [searchResults objectForKey:myEntityForDisplayCell.trackId];

UILabel *currentPrice = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1003];

if ([myEntityForDisplayCell.price1 floatValue] == [searchResultForDisplayCell.price2 floatValue]) {
   currentPrice.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
else if ([myEntityForDisplayCell.price1 floatValue] > [searchResultForDisplayCell.price2 floatValue])
{
    currentPrice.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.9 blue:0 alpha:1];
}
else if ([myEntityForDisplayCell.price1 floatValue] < [searchResultForDisplayCell.price2 floatValue])
{
    currentPrice.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

cell.backgroundColor = nil;

if (isLoading) {
    loadingHudView.numOne = [searchResults count];
    loadingHudView.numTwo = [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
    [loadingHudView setNeedsDisplay];
}

if ([searchResults count] == [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]) {

    [loadingHudView removeFromSuperview];

    if ([myEntityForDisplayCell.price1 floatValue] < [searchResultForDisplayCell.price2 floatValue]) {

        cell.backgroundColor = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.85 blue:0 alpha:0.45];
    }
}

}
```

**UPDATE 2:** Found something with the Analyser tool. I'm not entirely sure how it's a leak, but here goes anyway.

```
SearchResult *searchResult = [[SearchResult alloc] init];

for (id i in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
    MyEntity *myEntity = i;
    searchResult = [searchResults objectForKey:myEntity.id];
```

This bit of code will probably be executed once per everytime a new entity is added to the Core Data database, i.e. not particularly often.

Comment: Have you tried running the leaks tool under instruments? That will (fairly) definitively report if you are leaking memory.

Comment: @NathanS. Will do Nathan, just trying to fix a bug that seems to have occurred from my optimisation attempts. Will post back here with the results of the leak test, when sorted if that's ok.

Comment: Can you put some code out

Comment: @NathanS. Ok, weird results from the leak tests. I've been using it for the past 3 hours so I've got good information, which I forgot about! On one run about an hour ago I had a leak at one point with loads and loads of leaks. A further hour before that I had two consecutive runs with one leak each. Both suffered from OS_dispatch_queue. I have no idea what that means, however. Obviously the run where I leaked hundreds of objects was more severe, but I can't seem to recreate it. I'm going to have assume that I fixed the cause of the leaks when I was changing the code, I'll keep trying though.

Comment: @Srikanth Can you request some code to post? There's lots of it. I do network requests, loops through the core data to make changes, I set the fetchedResultsController to nil incase the user has changed the sorting option (I did turn this off to see if it was the cause of the problem, but as per my main post, I can't see how any code can be the cause), I do loads of calculations in my cell configuration. What interests you the most?

Comment: My guess is that you are creating new subviews and adding them to the cell each time, this would explain most of the symptoms you have.

Comment: @jrturton Very possibly. Just in the process of posting my code, there is a subview that I add to the cell. That could be what you're speaking of.

Comment: 1. Can you show us `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, too? 2. Just to confirm, I assume ARC. 3. Did you run your code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu) and get a clean bill of health? (On that last point, no point is us spending any time unless you have zero warnings from the analyzer.)

Comment: And what is that `cycleThroughEntriesAndSetSection`? That's a little worrying to see in a cell configuration method. And I'm suspect of any `addSubview` calls that are associated with some corresponding `removeFromSuperview` at some point.

Comment: @Rob Sure. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is simply: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListProto"];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        
    return cell;`

Comment: @Rob as for your other questions. I'm using ARC. I've never used the static analyser will have a look now. `cycleThroughEntriesAndSetSection` is a method that determines the section for each Core Data entity. it's very intensive, but it's only ever called once, and not for every cell. What are you referring to with regards to the `addSubview`? DYRateView? Where would I call `removeFromSuperview`?

Comment: @Rob, found a leak I think using the analyser. I'll edit the main post with it, but I don't really understand how it's a leak.

Comment: When I talk about `addSubview`, I was thinking of `rateViewForConfigureCell`. You have to remember that cells are reused again and again. So you're adding this to the cell again and again. You should give it a tag, and then do a `viewForTag`, if you don't find it, add it, otherwise use what's there. See my updated answer. Obviously replace my `1005` with whatever is appropriate. (To be honest, you shouldn't have hardcoded tag numbers in your code anyway, use `NSInteger` constants.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three observations:

1. You say "lots of images I'm pretty sure iOS removes things from the RAM as it begins to run out" -- FYI, if you're using `imageNamed`, it's not very good about managing your memory. When I'm doing image caching, I use my own `NSCache`. This is especially important if you're using large images.
2. See [WWDC 2012 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) for practical example of how to use Instruments to identify where your performance bottlenecks are.
3. Finally, see [Finding leaks with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW4) for guidance on how to use Instruments to find leaks. Also, don't overlook the [static analyzer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Analyze/Analyze.html), which is important if you don't use ARC, or if you use any Core Foundation calls.

Other than that, it's hard to identify sources of your problems without seeing code.

---

**Update:**

Now that you've provided a little source code, the one thing that leaps out at me is the `addSubview` of `rateViewForConfigureCell`. Given that cells are reused, you'll be adding that repeatedly to cells. So, I'd suggest replacing:

```
// The RateView for showing a start rating
rateViewForConfigureCell = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(73, 44, 75, 12) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullSmall.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptySmall.png"]];
rateViewForConfigureCell.rate = [searchResultForConfigureCell.rating floatValue];
rateViewForConfigureCell.alignment = RateViewAlignmentLeft;
[cell.contentView addSubview:rateViewForConfigureCell];
```

With:

```
// The RateView for showing a start rating
rateViewForConfigureCell = (DYRateView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1005]
if (!rateViewForConfigureCell) {
    rateViewForConfigureCell = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(73, 44, 75, 12) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullSmall.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptySmall.png"]];
    rateViewForConfigureCell.alignment = RateViewAlignmentLeft;
    rateViewForConfigureCell.tag = 1005;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rateViewForConfigureCell];
}
rateViewForConfigureCell.rate = [searchResultForConfigureCell.rating floatValue];
```

Either do that, or add the `DYRateView` to your cell prototype.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Rob, great links, +1. I'm posting code now, but it'll take a while as I comment everything so you guys can understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Excellent. thank you very much for the updated answer. So why shouldn't I be doing the checks for nil with the other objects, like the UILabels?

Comment: @Mackey18 Because they're added by the cell prototype, and it does that for you. You only need the construct that I've put in there for the programmatically added controls. Alternatively, you can add `DYRateView` to your cell prototype (though you can't pass the star images as parameters to the `init` method). By the way, if you create your own subclass for your cell prototype and put `IBOutlet` references in the .h file of that subclass, you don't even need to do your `viewWithTag` for those controls in the prototype cell, which minimizes the potential mistakes on `tag` numbers.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. One last thing. Where you say `(DYRateView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1005]` Why would we need a tag for that? Surely the contentView is the contentView and doesn't need that identifier, or am I looking at this completely wrong?

Comment: @Mackey18 You need the `tag` for your own purposes, to see if you've already added your programmatically created `DYRateView` to the cell. As you scroll, and a cell scrolls off the view, when the next cell appears at the bottom, it recycles the cell that scrolled off the screen (it's a way of saving the very precious memory on the device). But any controls you've added programmatically will still be there. So you want to search for the subview with that `tag` to see if you've already added the programmatically created `DYRateView` subview to the cell or not. Without a `tag`, that's tough.

Comment: Yup, I see that now. Silly me. Thank you for explaining yourself clearly and being patient, you've helped me to understand quite a few things, so I shouldn't make the same mistakes again. Greatly appreciated. Mike.

Answer (score 2):

As suspected, you are adding a new subview to the cell with every configuration run. This section of code:

```
// The RateView for showing a start rating
rateViewForConfigureCell = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(73, 44, 75, 12) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullSmall.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptySmall.png"]];
rateViewForConfigureCell.rate = [searchResultForConfigureCell.rating floatValue];
rateViewForConfigureCell.alignment = RateViewAlignmentLeft;
[cell.contentView addSubview:rateViewForConfigureCell];
```

Which is called every time, is allocating and adding a new view. After enough cycles your cell will have dozens of these, which will *look* perfectly normal, and may not take up huge amounts of memory, but will absolutely kill your performance, since the compositing engine has to take them all into account when it is scrolling your table up and down.

Any subviews like this should be added *once*, and just reconfigured in your configureCell method. Either add them when you get `nil` back from dequeuing the cell, or in the `init...` method of your cell subclass, or in the nib you are using to design the cell.

You seem to be doing something like this already with your other subviews (all those `viewWithTag:` calls) so I'm not sure why it isn't the case for this one.

Note that this may still not fix your performance problems - if there is "far more" than you have shown in the question, you won't get 60fps anyway - there is only a certain number of subviews you can have in a cell before the performance just dies off. There seems to be a lot going on here. You say you're a beginner - perhaps a less ambitious introduction project might be in order?

Comment: That's brilliant, I'll make the change right away. This is the only subview I add by the way, when I said there's far more, I meant far more labels that I add (about 6 more) or is a label considered a subview of the UITableViewCell? So just doing it the same way as I did with the labels etc. using viewWithTag, will fix the problem? Fantastic. +1 for great answer.